# Intuitive explanation why the integral of $\sin(x)$ is $-\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I realize there's a bunch of similar questions, but for derivative. However, this is a little bit different.

I understand pretty well why derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ and of $\cos(x)$ is $-\sin(x)$. That makes sense, since derivative expresses the "angle of normal", I can see that from graph easily.

However, when I try to - analogically, using a graph - find integral of $\sin(x)$, I can't seem to make sense of it.

Here's my graphs:

[image]

I know that integral is "area under graph". If you look at graph of $\sin(x)$, it starts with zero area under the graph and gradually more is added, with growing speed, then it slows down and eventually stops at $\pi$, where the derivative reaches zero. Then as the graph goes under the $x$ axis, the area is subtracted again and eventually it reaches zero at $2 \pi$.

That doesn't quite add up with $-\cos(x)$, does it? It would make sense if it was as it's on my 3rd picture.

I probably understand it wrong, so please give me some hint how to understand it... the point is, I never remember the formulas, and I'm reasonably successful with finding the derivatives, but never get the integral right.

Comment: Your third picture looks pretty much like $-\cos$. Perhaps a bit of vertical translation would make them equal, eh?

Comment: I suppose... so does that mean that the integration constant is `1` then?

Comment: You're talking about integrals and antiderivatives. So when you compare the "area under the graph" of $\sin(x)$ from $[a,b]$ you are just looking at $-\cos(b) + \cos(a)$ rather than the area of the graph for the $-\cos(x)$. Actually you should look up antiderivatives and the fundamental theorem of calculus and it will help you understand why the integrals must be that way. You could also look up the exponential form and series form of sin and cos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you talk about integrals, you could be talking about one of many distinct, but related topics. You could mean Riemann integrals, indefinite integrals, or many other types of integral out there.

You're probably talking about the indefinite integral when you say that the integral of $\sin$ is $-\cos$. The thing about the indefinite integral is that it is not really a single function. That's why you often display it with the little ${}+C$ at the end. An indefinite integral is more like a set of functions, which are all equal under vertical translations.

So, $\int f$ could be considered the set of functions which have a derivative $f$. There are many functions which have the derivative $\sin$, and they are all of the form $-\cos+C$, where $C$ is some real number. This is why it is said the integral of $\sin$ is $-\cos$.

But why does the integral then not represent the area? Well, it does. What you were saying was that $-\cos(x)$ should be the area under $\sin(x)$ up to $x$. The question is, up to $x$ from where? There is no lower bound! If you pick the lower bound $0$, then

$$-\cos(x)-(-\cos(0))=-\cos(x)+1$$

You get that $+1$ you were wondering about, and it does represent the area under $\sin(x)$ from $0$ to $x$.

Comment: This answer is far from perfect, but I hope it is of at least some use to you.

Comment: Yep it's a good explanation, just doesn't help much with "figuring out" it's `-cos(x)`, like I can do for the derivative using the slope... I'll have to just remember it, I guess

Comment: @MightyPork: You could try this: Do as you did when making your third image. Then imagine what function the graph could represent if you moved it up or down. For example, you may notice that moving your third image down by $1$ makes it look like $-\cos$.

Comment: that's good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right as far as area goes but remember that the integral is only defined up to a constant!

Numerically if you were directly comparing areas then the function you would need would be $1-\cos{x}$. However recall that this is indefinite integration.